# Deleting top 5% and bottom 5% of all records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Customer ID, MDN, Plan, StartDate, EndDate, Term, SMS Usage, Voice Usage
```

Ordering by SMS Usage in ascending or descending order

I want to delete the top 5% of all records, and the bottom 50% leaving behind the remaining 90% of customers

Comment: % based on what--number of records? Actual usage? ...?

Comment: I think your math is off - you want top 5% and bottom 5%, not top 5% and bottom 50%, right?

Comment: and you want to do it in one statement? you can always use `string sql = "select top " + myCalculated5Percent + " from ... order by ...";`

Comment: @Yuck: Probably implying that 90% of the usage is made up of values not falling within the other percentages. (But I agree with you).

Comment: @Yuck - 55 & 5? You mean 50 & 5? I think the OP has obviously made as mistake, as have you.

Comment: Re-tagged as SQL-Server-2008 since the user is not using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID FROM 
    (
      SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT CustomerID FROM dbo.table 
      ORDER BY [SMS Usage]
    ) AS lowest
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerID FROM
    (
      SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT CustomerID FROM dbo.table
      ORDER BY [SMS Usage] DESC
    ) AS highest
)
-- DELETE t FROM dbo.table AS t INNER JOIN x ON t.CustomerID = x.CustomerID;
SELECT CustomerID FROM t;
```

When you are happy that the query is returning the right rows, you can uncomment the `DELETE` and comment or remove the last line.

Comment: OMG I did it again, I meant 5%

Comment: Your delete needs to actually delete from the base table not t.

Comment: @HLGEM thanks, updated. I forgot about the restriction on `UNION` queries inside CTEs. However this isn't always the case - without a `UNION` you can delete from the CTE and it parlays to the base table.

Comment: See I learned something too, I never have considered a CTE as an updateable view (maybe becasue I generally don't update through views) before. But the Union is still an issue for this particular one.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT CustomerID
INTO #TopPct
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY SMSUsage;

SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT CustomerID
INTO #BottomPct
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY SMSUsage DESC;

DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE CustomerID IN (
  SELECT CustomerID FROM #TopPct
  UNION
  SELECT CustomerID FROM #BottomPct
);
```

The first two queries are gathering the top and bottom percent of records. The last query uses the found records in both (`#TopPct` and `#BottomPct`) to select records for deletion.

Comment: Turns out the user is NOT running SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Haha, typos abound!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ntile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx).

```
;with C as
(
  select ntile(20) over(order by SMSUsage) as nt
  from YourTable       
)      
delete from C
where nt in (1,20)
```

Try on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62700/ntile-delete)