# Select top/bottom 5% with groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as such:

| Department | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 9 |
| B | 10 |

I want to select only the top/bottom eg.20% of 'Value' within each Department.

i.e Result:

| Department | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 10 |

I've tried using the solution: [Deleting top 5% and bottom 5% of all records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486313/deleting-top-5-and-bottom-5-of-all-records)

However this will calculate the top/bottom % based on all values rather than within each department.

Is there a way to do this? Note: I've got over 2k different departments.

Comment: [edit] into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NTILE` built in function to group the data into different groups. In your case, it will be 5 group (each 20% will fall into one group).

```sql
declare @t table(Department char(1), Value int)

insert into @t values
('A',1  ),
('A',2  ),
('A',3  ),
('A',4  ),
('A',5  ),
('B',6  ),
('B',7  ),
('B',8  ),
('B',9  ),
('B',10 );

SELECT Department, value
from
(select Department, value, NTILE(5) over(partition by department order by value) as group_num from @t) as t
where group_num in (1,5)
```

| Department | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 10 |

Comment: This is the answer thank you!

Comment: @Smc, please accept the answer. It will be helpful for future visitors of the site.

Comment: I've accepted the answer thanks for the guidance

Comment: @Smc. cool. you are welcome.